# Does drawing diagrams lead to 36% higher scores when solving science problems?

Tags: learning

Microsoft claims in their [Windows 10 press release](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/06/29/windows-10-anniversary-update-available-august-2/) that drawing diagrams leads to 36% higher scores when solving science problems.

> More than 70% of people spend more than one hour a day using a pen. Yet, we lose notes in our notebooks, take pictures of whiteboards, and don’t have the option to do equations or music composition with a keyboard. Writing is also a key part of the creative and learning process. Studies indicate students learn better by writing. **For example, diagramming before solving a science problem can lead to 36% higher scores**.

Is this claim supported by any research?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See page 61 of [The Design of Future Educational Interfaces](https://books.google.com/books?id=raqAAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&lpg=PA60&dq=before%20solving%20a%20science%20problem%20can%20lead%20to%2036%25%20higher%20scores&source=bl&ots=gBZaX70bNR&sig=UbZXTD96M6Ni2w1vw88XcYsbRds&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitx830jZTOAhXs7IMKHfuLAhgQ6AEINzAF#v=onepage&q=before%20solving%20a%20science%20problem%20can%20lead%20to%2036%25%20higher%20scores&f=false) :

> An analysis of matched pairs of problems revealed that when biology students constructed diagrams their scores averaged 36% ... In addition to facilitating hypothesis generation, students' active construction of diagrams and thinking marks was associated with 25–36% higher problem-solution scores, compared with matched problems in which students did no marking.

Which is based upon: [The Impact of Interface Affordances on Human Ideation, Problem
Solving, and Inferential Reasoning](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2362370) ACM Transactions on Computer-Human Interaction (TOCHI) Volume 19 Issue 3, October 2012 Article No. 22 :

> 2.2.4. *Active Pen Marking Associated with Improved Problem Solving.* All 16 students produced
>   both diagrams and informal thinking marks while working on biology problems.
>   As shown in Figure 6(a), an analysis of matched pairs of problems revealed that when
>   students constructed diagrams, their scores averaged significantly higher than when
>   they did not ( ¯x = 82% vs. 46%, respectively), paired t = 4.27 (df 19), p < 0.001,
>   one-tailed. This difference represents a substantial 36% absolute improvement.